django-ckeditor-5 unable to upload file on local and not showing preview of youtube link
I successfully display the ckeditor5 using django-ckeditor-5 package, but not able to upload images and not able to show youtube video on the result page.
Here is what I get errors on backend console and browser.
Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /ckeditor5/image_upload/
WARNING 2024-04-08 09:40:09,120 log 10 135125224380160 Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header has incorrect length.): /ckeditor5/image_upload/
INFO:     172.19.0.1:54724 - "POST /ckeditor5/image_upload/ HTTP/1.1" 403 Forbidden




It is definitely about the csrf token, but it should be handled by the package. When I was watching youtube tutorials and blogs, no one is configuring about csrf token.
Here is some information of my project.
I started the project with cookiecutter-django running with docker. I configured settings using tailwindcss/flowbite. frontend pipeline using webpack.

While I was writing this, I found an answer for showing youtube link on detail page, and my friend helped me solve uploading images.
First, to show youtube link on detail page, you should add the below on settings for CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS
"extends": {
        ....
        "mediaEmbed": {"previewsInData": "true"},
    },

I found this answer from the github issue
For the uploading issue, basically, cookiecutter-django has default setting like below for security part.
# SECURITY
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-httponly
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#x-frame-options
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"

If I change CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to False, uploading images successfully.
Now this bring up another question. Is it ok to make it false? Will there be any serious security issues?
